# How to better construct a SQL statement with values from a Data Frame?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dataframe

consider the following SQL statement:

```
q="SELECT H_ID, CREATION_DATE FROM HOTEL WHERE H_ID IN (700,701,702...)"
```

the values in the parenthesis should come from a Data Frame:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"H_ID":[701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710],"B":[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2], "C":[4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,2]})
```

at the moment, what I do is this?

```
#convert H_ID column to a string separated by comma
my_ids = str(list(df["H_ID"].apply(lambda x : str(x)))).replace("[","").replace("]","")
```

and I add it to my query:

```
q="SELECT H_ID, CREATION_DATE FROM HOTEL WHERE H_ID IN ("+my_ids+")"
```

Question: is there a better way to do this by avoiding the conversion to string?

Comment: Insert the values in to a *(temporary)* table, then join on that table.  But then you need to stringify everything to insert in to the table.  It's not pretty however you go.  Unless you reach the limit where it stops working, I'd stick with your current process.  *(It all comes down to "how do I get a long list of values from my client to the MySQL server?"  The answer is never pretty.)*

Comment: @MatBailie thank you! is there another way without using sql query per-se? (like setParameters (x,df["H_ID"]) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy

df=pd.DataFrame({"H_ID":[701,702,703,704,705,706,707,708,709,710],"B":[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,2], "C":[4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,2]})
s = ', '.join(map(str, df['H_ID'].as_matrix()))
q = 'SELECT H_ID, CREATION_DATE FROM HOTEL WHERE H_ID IN ({})'.format(s)
print(q)
```

Output:

```
SELECT H_ID, CREATION_DATE FROM HOTEL WHERE H_ID IN (701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710)
```